# Percentage based on criteria in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to figure out how to get a percentage row at the bottom of my table below.

```
SD    a    b     c        d       e
D   2168 1545   2163    1540    2153
S   435   212   410      193    391
T   13208 5438  12935   5337    12656
```

I would like to divide rows D and S by row T to create two new percentage rows. Is this possible?
Output would look like this:

```
 SD   a       b      c        d       e
D   2168    1545    2163    1540    2153
S   435      212    410      193    391
T   13208    5438   12935   5337    12656
D/T 0.164    0.284  0.167   0.288   0.170
S/T 0.033    0.04   0.032   0.04    0.031
```

I just need the percentages, so this doesn't necessarily need to be in the table, but if it is then that's also fine.

TIA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This might be better done in your presentation layer, if you're mixing aggregated and non-aggregated data.

Comment: Are those the only rows in the table?

Comment: @Larnu to Becky's point, [SQL Server has a built in function to do similar aggregations](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/24/sql-server-introduction-to-rollup-clause/)

Comment: @scsimon Yes, but if you're using `ROLLUP` then you're already using aggregated data (and a `GROUP BY` clause). I did say **if** you're mixing aggregated and non-aggregated. :)

Comment: @scsimon, if they aren't, they could easily become the only rows in a CTE.

Comment: ROLLUP returns aggregated and non-aggregated data @Larnu, so I'm not following what you mean.

Comment: True @TabAlleman I was trying to avoid follow on questions

Comment: @scsimon no it doesn't It provides a higher level total; like that link you provided shows (the author even calls them "Total" in their labelling). If you have multiple columns in your `GROUP BY` it'll "roll up" (sub total) each one in order. `ROLLUP` doesn't "de-aggregate", it simply adds more aggregate values.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't  "de-aggregate" but it returns aggregated values with the original non-aggregated data set, thus the result set contains aggregated totals and the original data.. which is a mix IMHO @Larnu

Comment: Perhaps better explained with a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/115b8/2). notice the last result set contains the value *`NULL`* in places, due to no aggregation in the original query.

Comment: @scsimon those are the only rows in the table, I am just looking to create two percentages. They don't necessarily need to be in the table as I don't actually need the data that is in the table, just the percentages. thanks

Comment: @Larnu I have tried a pivot but cannot get the pivot to work with so many columns. Any way to get the percentages of d/t and s/t would be great.

Comment: @Larnu i'm aware of that... but somehow I'm unable to illustrate that even your demo contains rows of data which is the result of an aggregate, and rows which are not.

Comment: @BeckyPurland have you tried solutions below?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work using a union in order to pivot the data so I have created a percentage column. It is a bit clunky though as it takes 5 1/2 minutes to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.sd, t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e
from t
union all
select sd.sd + '/T', sd.a * 1.0 / t.a, sd.b * 1.0 / t.b, sd.c * 1.0 / t.c,
       sd.d * 1.0 / t.d, sd.e * 1.0 / t.d
from t sd cross join
     (select t2.* from t t2 where sd = 'T') tt
where sd in ('D', 'S');
```

Although in practice this returns the rows in the order you want, that is not guaranteed.  Also note that the final columns will all have the same type.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am trying to give this one a go, I am confused about the t2.* section in the cross join. Where are you getting t2 from? Do you mean (select t.* from t where sd = 'T') ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is messy but it works- replace #temp with your table name

```
select *, row_number() over (order by SD)rownum into #temp2 from #temp 


select *from #temp2   
union
select 'D/T',(select a from #temp2 where sd='D')/ cast((select a from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select b from #temp2 where sd='D')/ cast((select b from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
  (select c from #temp2 where sd='D')/ cast((select c from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select d from #temp2 where sd='D')/ cast((select d from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select e from #temp2 where sd='D')/ cast((select e from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float), 
 (select max(rownum)+1 from #temp2)
 union
select 'S/T',(select a from #temp2 where sd='S')/ cast((select a from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select b from #temp2 where sd='S')/ cast((select b from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
  (select c from #temp2 where sd='S')/ cast((select c from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select d from #temp2 where sd='S')/ cast((select d from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float),
 (select e from #temp2 where sd='S')/ cast((select e from #temp2 where sd='T')  as float), 
 (select max(rownum)+2 from #temp2)
 order by rownum
```